# External Reference using AVERAGEIF

Tags: excel, file, sharepoint, external

I wrote this function on Excel ina database workbook, but it return the value error:

`ROUND(AVERAGEIF([RECEBIMENTO DE CAIXA - TESTE.xlsx]JAN'!$B$16:$AF$16;"<>0");0)`

The both files are in a SharePoint, in the same folder.

How can I resolve this problem?

```
ARRED(MÉDIASE('https://patrus.sharepoint.com/sites/Intranet/fiscal/Tesouraria/TESOURARIA/19. Erick/[RECEBIMENTO DE CAIXA - TESTE.xlsx]JAN'!$B$16:$AF$16;"<>0");0)
```

Answer (score 0):

On my own computer, I'm not able to use the function "AVERAGEIF", if the second file is closed. If the file is closed, I have the result "#Value". So, try to open the other file to verify if you will have the right calculation.